base-uri function in Schematron compiled with schxslt and saxonCS
i have an xml file and .sch file to validate this xml file. But there are some rules calls <xsl:param name="dosyaAdi" select="base-uri()"/>. base-uri() function returns null and all the controls according to this function are failing.
I have compiled my sch file with schxslt's compile-for-svrl.xsl Then I pass my xml and xslt to Saxon to transform. It transforms well. But I guess some how base-uri() function in sch returns null and 2 rules depending on it, fails. here is my code sample.
    string schxsltSvrlXsltResource = @"SchematronSchxsltSaxonCSValidator/schxslt195/compile-for-svrl.xsl";
    var schxsltResourceUri = UriUtils.GetLocationUri(schxsltSvrlXsltResource, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    var resolver = new Resolver();

    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings() { XmlResolver = resolver };

    var processor = new Processor(true);
    var xsltCompiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();

    using var schxsltReader = XmlReader.Create(schxsltResourceUri.AbsoluteUri, settings);


    var transformer = xsltCompiler.Compile(schxsltReader).Load30();
    //var compiledSchxslt = xsltCompiler.Compile(schxsltReader).Load30();

    var compiledSchematron = new XdmDestination();
    compiledSchematron.BaseUri = new Uri(new FileInfo(inputSch).FullName);

    using var schemaStream = File.OpenRead(inputSch);

    transformer.Transform(schemaStream, compiledSchematron);

    var xsltCompiler2 = processor.NewXsltCompiler();

    var schematronValidator = xsltCompiler2.Compile(compiledSchematron.XdmNode).Load30();

    var svrlResult = new XdmDestination(); 
    using var instanceStream = File.OpenRead(inputXml);
    //schematronValidator.Run(svrlResult);
    schematronValidator.Transform(instanceStream, svrlResult);

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(svrlResult.XdmNode.OuterXml);

    var failedNodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("svrl:failed-assert");
    foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode node in failedNodes)
    {

    }


There is an overload of the Transform method https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/Xslt30Transformer.html#Transform(Stream,Uri,IDestination) that allows you to set the base Uri so instead of
schematronValidator.Transform(instanceStream, svrlResult);

try
schematronValidator.Transform(instanceStream, new Uri(new FileInfo(inputXml).FullName),  svrlResult);

If that doesn't work then consider to show a stack trace and the exact line where you get the error.

You're a life saver! Thank u for the effort. Your knowledge enlightened me during this process. I didn't see that overload. Thank You!!

Also, I want to ask. Is there any possible way to retrieve error messages from transformation ? I am trying to retrieve them by filtering elements in response that contains failed-assert. But I am not sure will it cause any performance issue or not. I saw a messageListener class in Saxon validator but it didn't call the method I have supplied

The Schematron validation is just an application of XSLT 2 or 3 that creates an XML document in the form of an SVRL report, in that document you can look for all the error messages. Your code seems to do that although by creating an XmlDocument, which seems unnecessary. You should be able to select the failed assert directly from svrlResult.XdmNode. As for a message listener, that is used to capture any xsl:messages from an XSLT stylesheet but as far as I know Schxslt doesn't emit xsl:messages for Schematron validation, it creates an SVRL report where you can look for failed asserts.

Yes, you're right. I have figured the whole process out. SVRL is just reporting it as failed assert. not giving xsl message. That's why I can not implement a messageListener. But I couldn't find a way to collect failed-asserts from xdmNode. Can you also share an example, please?

Also, when I try to get the location of the current failed node from attribute like <svrl:failed-assert location="/Q{http://www.edefter.gov.tr}defter[1]/Q{http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance}xbrl[1]/Q{http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/cor/2006-10-25}accountingEntries[1]/Q{http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/cor/2006-10-25}entryHeader[1130]" I guess I have to import the namespaces to get specific path like "gl-cor:accountingEntried[1]" instead of "{http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/cor/2006-10-25}accountingEntries[1]"

Look at the SaxonCS documentation and samples for XdmNode on how to navigate/extract data from XdmNodes. If you can't figure it out for an SVRL document then consider to raise that as a separate question. The same for the location, that seems to be Schematron/Schxslt/SVRL related, raise that as a separate question, I think the format you see is the result of the XPath 3 path function which has the advantage of being evaluable as XPath 3 without setting up namespace binding but is obviously verbose/repetitive in terms of QName URIs.

Navigation sample is at https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxonmirrorhe/repository/he/revisions/he_mirror_saxon_12_5/entry/src/samples/cs/Examples.cs#L225. Or use XPath (not necessary for the rather flat SVRL structure but an option certainly) https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxonmirrorhe/repository/he/revisions/he_mirror_saxon_12_5/entry/src/samples/cs/Examples.cs#L279
